# JDialog property changed behaviour

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog, propertychanged

I have implemented a JDialog which is along the lines of the top answer seen in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055107/joptionpane-check-user-input-and-prevent-from-closing-until-conditions-are-met). The code works entirely apart from the fact that when an invalid input is provided, two `PropertyChangedEvents` occur when only one is desired. This led to the formulation of the SSCCE below:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test{  
    public Test(){
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(null, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(new JFrame(), "Test", true);
        dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);

        optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                String prop = e.getPropertyName();

                if (dialog.isVisible() && (e.getSource() == optionPane) && (JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop))){
                    java.lang.System.out.println("Code Reached");
                    optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

From this SSCCE, it is possible to tell that the second, and unwanted, `PropertyChangedEvent` is caused by the line of code `optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE)`; this code however is neccessary to prevent the window locking up after invalid inputs. Is there a way to either prevent the `JOptionPane.setValue()` from causing a `PropertyChangedEvent`, or to determine when the `PropertyChangedEvent`has been caused by resetting the value of the JOptionPane and prevent  the `if` occuring? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible for you to disable the event listener, you could do it by:

A) set a (boolean) flag in the PropertyChangeListener object

or

B) remove the eventlistener from the optionPane:

```
final PropertyChangeListener pcl = new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String prop = e.getPropertyName();

        if (dialog.isVisible() && (e.getSource() == optionPane) && (JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop))){
            java.lang.System.out.println("Code Reached");
            optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);

            optionPane.removePropertyChangeListener(pcl);
        }
    }
}
optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
```

However, this depends on the dialogs purpose. If you close the dialog, then option B is good.

**EDIT:**

The second event is caused by `optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE)` , so if you check against that value, it could work.

```
if (dialog.isVisible() 
        && e.getSource() == optionPane 
        && JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop)
        && !optionPane.getValue().equals(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE)){

    java.lang.System.out.println("Code Reached");
    optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Currently I am using a workaround similar to A, whereby I toggle a boolean; this however seems like a bit of a dodgy solution. Unforunately I cannot just remove the listener, as I want the JDialog to remain on screen, and clickable, until a valid input has been provided (or in the case of the provided SSCCE, it needs to remain indefinately.)

Comment: The edit is perfect, I cannot believe I didn't see it!