# How to retain showConfirmDialog on, after user yes/cancel choice

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, joptionpane

I have a `JOptionPane.confirmDialog` which contains `JTextField` areas inside of a `JPanel`. I have also some constraints which prevent invalid input of data by the user. As it is now, there is an alert message which informs the user of a possible field wrong input. But the previous confirmation dialog disappears after pressing ok. I want it to stay on, and possibly highlight the wrongly inputted `JTextField`.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
myPanel.add(new JLabel("Customer name (Name Surname):"));
myPanel.add(cname);

result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "Please Enter Contract Fields", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: Create your own JDialog and use it in place of the JOptionPane. Otherwise you will need to re-show the JOptionPane if data is invalid.

Comment: any clues how to do that?

Comment: Yes. Please see answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055107/joptionpane-check-user-input-and-prevent-from-closing-until-conditions-are-met)

Comment: Other similar questions can be found [in this Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+joptionpane+validate+fields)